# Changed from HTTP to HTTP, can login no longer login

Tags: login, https

I changed my whole website to `https` from `http`.

Now I can no longer log into my admin area. I always get a redirect loop. I changed my WordPress URL in "General settings" to `https`, how can I solve this problem and how can I manage to log in again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have HTTPS set up correct. To revert back to HTTP and regain access to your admin area, do the following:

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://example.com/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. In the "*search for…*" and "*replace with…*" fields:

   - **Replace**: `https://example.com` (from HTTPS)
   - **With**: `http://example.com` (back to HTTP)

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

Additionally, you can also look into using the [Remove HTTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-http/) plugin which automatically scans your website and removes both HTTP and HTTPS protocols from your URL links.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! It worked fine,
Now everything is fine except one thing, maybe you can help me too? It is about stripe for woocommerce. I use cloudflare SSL, but same problem here, Stripe is not displayed as payment option because it requires "force SSL at checkout" checked. But if I check it, same problem, when going to checkout again getting redirect loop

Comment: That's a separate question from the original. Please click the checkmark next to this answer to indicate this question has been solved. Then open up a new question with more details so the community can help you better.